# How can I fix this Ruby Yes/No-Style Loop?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I've got this method I wrote to ask *n-times* for user input using a *while loop* inside.
The idea is really simple and common, repeat the while loop if the condition is true, 
The problem is that it doesn't work...

```
def play_again?
  flag = true
  while flag
    print "Would you like to play again? [y/n]: "
    response = gets.chomp
    case response
      when 'y'
        Game.play
      when 'n'
        flag = false
    end
  end
  flag
end

play_again?
```

As it stands it will only successfully repeat once and then exit, instead of keep on looping, Could you guys please tell me what is wrong?
(Sorry if it's such a n00b question, I'm a ruby n00b after all)

Thank you.

Comment: just tried your code in a ruby console, and it works fine

Comment: If you replace `Game.play` with `puts "playing..."` it works fine. Something in your `Game` is messing up.

Comment: You're correct, both of you. apparently Game.play was returning nil
I didn't realize that could be a factor as the loop variable is 'unrelated'

Comment: Not a thing wrong with it. It repeats if the input is anything other than (lower case) `y` or `n`. There is nothing wrong with `Game.play` in this case other than it being undefined. I would only suggest `response = gets.chomp.downcase` to accept `Y` or `N` as well.

Comment: Game.play returning nil should not exit your while loop

Comment: Hi!, I fixed it. And as stated even in the first comment, the loop was totally fine, the problem was related to something entirely different inside the Game.play logic. Thank you for making me realize my loop was almost correct. All your help is always nice and appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible problems:

- check Game.play
- Capital/no-capital in the answer? -> String#upcase or String#downcase
- hidden spaces (before/after the answer) -> String#strip instead String#chomp

You may also use regular expressions (example N) or with a list of answers (yes) to check the answer:

```
def play_again?
  while true
    print "Would you like to play again? [y/n]: "
    case gets.strip
      when 'Y', 'y', 'j', 'J', 'yes' #j for Germans (Ja)
        puts 'I play' # Game.play
      when /\A[nN]o?\Z/ #n or no
        break 
    end
  end
end

play_again?
```

Comment: Your loop is quite better, more trimmed down and idiomatic. I give you thanks for making me realize how to do it well, and that basically, my version was almost ok. Thanks once more.